# Create a Python package with both Python code and a Cython extension

Tags: python, package, cython

Is it possible to create a Python wheel (or egg) with both Python packages and a Cython extension module? I looked for examples and found none.

How can I do that? I'd rather not create two packages, as the Cython extension module has absolutely no use outside the Python package.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it's very simple - create a `setup.py` file with both packages and extension modules. Setuptools takes care of everything else.